# Opening the charm menu in a windows 8 app, using Okra Framework

Tags: xaml, okra-framework

I would like to make a button using xaml that will open the charms menu on press.  Does anybody know how to do this?  I am also using the Okra Framework, not sure if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking to open a specific settings page that is on the settings charm menu? If so, follow this.

With Okra, you can get a reference to the SettingsPaneManager on your viewmodel:

```
[Import]
public ISettingsPaneManager SettingsPaneManager { get; set; }
```

In your command's function on your viewmodel:

```
SettingsPaneManager.NavigateTo("NameOfPage");
```